# stop function running when a div has a certain class

Tags: jquery, mobile

my mobile app has a sidebar/ side menu, that opens when you click the little menu icon.

when the sidebar is open, I prevent scrolling using a touchmove eventlistener and e.preventDefault();

I also want to prevent any click-able divs on the page from being able to run their attached functions (some of the page is still in view when the sidebar is open, much like the facebook app).

I could check if the sidebar is open in every function like:

```
if( ! $('#main-wrapper').hasClass('show-right-menu') ){
    // run code
}
```

but there are a lot of functions i would need to add this to, is there a better way?

Comment: You can set a variable in global scope when you change the class and compare that in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation I like to use an overlay div, you can also use the div to fade the content which looks nice.

Basically you cover your content with a div and listen for events on that div which then closes the menu.

Here is a quick example which you can hopefully get the idea from:

http://jsfiddle.net/vSbcQ/5/

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="menu-button">
            menu
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
         Lots of wonderful amazing content
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.addEventListener` and set the 3rd parameter to `true`. That will make it fire first before any other `click` listeners.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(!$('#main-wrapper').hasClass('show-right-menu')) return false; // we don't need this if the menu is closed
    if(!$(e.target).parents(".right-menu").length) { // if the target is not located in the menu, we cancel the click
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

Here is a quick live example http://jsfiddle.net/Hngvx/